# jQuery Mobile 1.2 autodividers work inconsistently

Tags: jquery-mobile

If I create a list view of academics and display their title eg. Prof Joe Bloggs the auto dividers work, if I remove the title and just list Joe Bloggs no more auto dividers?

Below is a code snippet:

```
<ul data-role="listview"  data-filter="true" data-autodividers="true">
    @foreach (var academic in Model)
    {
      <li >@academic.Name ()</li> 
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that some of the names in the databases started with white space, so after trimming it off it all works as expected.